# Disable mouse interference in Cmd-Tab overlay?

Tags: macos

I often use <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> with my right hand on the mouse. If the cursor happens to be within overlay, then any accidental mouse movement causes OS X to think that I want to switch to whichever window icon the cursor lands on.

Meanwhile, I am used to Windows' behavior, where the mouse has no effect on <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.  I don't want to think, pause, check anything, or correct anything when I use <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>; I press the combo and intend to instantly switch to the previous app.  The mouse simply interferes with this.

---

[image]

---

Is it possible to turn off this "feature"?

Comment: Oops, I am so used to the term "Alt-Tab" that I didn't adapt it to the Mac. I meant Cmd+Tab. (Tangentially, I don't know how to create key characters like you did; markdown help doesn't mention it.)

Comment: I used the method shown in [this answer](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1282/37797).

Comment: Thanks. On-topic, yesterday I discovered that Windows _also_ takes mouse input in its task-switcher overlay.  However, because the overlay is smaller, the odds of the mouse being inside are smaller, so I never noticed.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but this question makes no sense to me. Which "feature" are you attempting to disable? You are describing the behavior of a keystroke shortcut and the behavior of the mouse/trackpad when gliding over the window when brought up. What other behavior would one expect when the two coalesce?

Comment: @njboot, not when gliding over *the window*, but when gliding over the app icon in the task switcher overlay.

Comment: My case is that I am intentionally moving both cursor and cmd-tab because I wanted to cut edges and save time... I knew the button I need to click is on the top left corner of the next window; why do I need to wait my left hand to finish cmd-tabbing (which might take a whole second if I need to move more than one window) when my right hand could multi-task and move the cursor? Therefore, I still want to move my cursor. I just don't want the app switcher overlay to capture cursor motion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent mouse interaction with Keyboard Maestro's app switcher:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Alternatively, you can lock the mouse position whilst the ⌘ key is still held down:

[image]

However, this doesn't appear to be possible without third party tools. You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this on the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 3):

### defining the Problem

What you're talking about is a kind of [focus stealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stealing). In OS X it happens in many instances, but always either by how you describe with the pointer stealing focus, an application event stealing focus, or a System event stealing focus. This problem has vexed OS X users for years, and is at odds with the older X windows users that prefer that [Focus Follows Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_follows_mouse). The result of this conflict is that it is far easier to find settings or third-party software that gives Focus Follows Mouse functionality than it is to find settings or software that prevent the pointer or applications from stealing focus.

Others feeling your pain have posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/155468/disabling-focus-stealing-in-mac-os-x), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/87819/is-there-a-way-to-keep-applications-in-mac-os-x-from-stealing-focus), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/56589/is-there-a-way-in-mac-os-x-to-stop-applications-from-stealing-focus-especially), [a massive thread here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2327656?start=0&tstart=0), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/11547728#11547728), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/11547728#11547728), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21536095#21536095), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17279302#17279302), [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1652326), [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4956771), and [here](http://mac.bigresource.com/OS-X-Leopard-How-to-prevent-apps-from-stealing-focus-61Gs4DBNI.html), and the list goes on and on and on... and there is hardly a definitive solution.

Personally, I have nearly given my machine the ability to fly when experiencing the focus stealing issue in this way: I am prompted for an administrative password, and *right then,* someone sends a chat message to me, the chat window steals focus, and inadvertantly and unintentionally, I enter my password in the chat window and hit return, sending my admin password to them. Compared to this, I'm afraid, your complaint pales, and I think you can see why.

In general, focus is determined on a per application basis, and some applications, such as Terminal and X11, which by default do not have Focus Follows Mouse enabled, have hooks to [achieve that functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98310/focus-follows-mouse-plus-auto-raise-on-mac-os-x/98331#98331) using the [defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) command. These were the inspiration for my suggestions involving the defaults command below. The Application Switcher is actually a part of the Dock.app, and it, apparently does not have this functionality built-in (thank you grgarside for testing).

I'm doing my best to research this, and I believe I have some viable solutions for you.

---

### [Zooom/2](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/)

Zooom/2 will allow you to set a delay to the focus-follows-mouse functionality of the pointer where ever it does this. This will have the effect of giving you the functionality you're seeking, preventing the pointer from stealing focus with the Application Switcher. Its $19.95 but there is a [Free Trial](http://software.coderage-software.com/zooom/Zooom_Latest.dmg) <-- download link

---

### Alternatives

#### Use a second display? Then move Application Switcher there

As detailed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/how-to-choose-on-which-display-application-switcher-shows/106280#106280). If you work with two displays, presumably, your pointer is usually going to be on your primary display. Move the Application Switcher to your secondary display, and your pointer won't interact with it.

#### Make your Mouse Pointer more visable

[Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/) from Boinx Software ($4.99 on the Mac [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/mousepose/id405904955?mt=12)) has the ability to change the color of your cursor, making it more visible, thus reducing the chance that you won't notice it is hovering over your Application Switcher. Also, like Zooom/2 mentioned above, it gives the functionality of introducing a delay before implementing Focus Follows Mouse functionality, mitigating the problem of focus stealing.

If you make your pointer larger, there is less of a chance you won't notice that its hovering over the Application Switcher. You can give this a try by adjusting the  System Preferences/Accessability Control Panel/Display/Cursor Size Slider :

[image: change pointer size]

---

#### [MondoMouse](http://www.atomicbird.com/about/mac-apps)

Atomic Bird's MondoMouse may be able to

#### [Virtual Desktop Pro](http://www.codetek.com/ctvd/)

Codetek's Virtual Desktop Pro might do it (for $40), is well regarded by users if not by Apple.

note: these two apps are really for adding the Focus Follows Mouse functionality to the System, which is the opposite of your requst to prevent the pointer from focus stealing with Application Switcher. Also note that neither of these two applications are actively still developed, and Atomic Bird software is free.

---

#### Experiment with the [defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) command

The way people find those secret hidden defaults settings is, by and large, by experimenting and trial and error. You're not going to hurt anything, or do something that can't be undone by doing so.

Fire up ye olde Terminal.app and give this a try:

```
 defaults write com.apple.dock FocusFollowsMouse -string false; killall Dock
```

---

The [Application Switcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_switcher#Macintosh) (or <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> ;-) is actually part of Dock.app. I'm not sure what this will do with the behavior of Dock-proper because I can't test it right now (building stuff, so I can't log out right now). I would wager a guess that it doesn't change anything with the Dock-proper, because that is already the behavior with the Dock (you have to click on something in the Dock, or click and hold, already - though it might break Dock-proper mouse-over info, which just tells you the app name).

What this should do is exactly what you want, cause the mouse pointer to ignore the Application Switcher unless you click the mouse button.

You can reverse this behavior by changing false to true in the above command.

---

grgarside? Thanks for volunteering how about:

```
  defaults write com.apple.dock FocusFollowsMouse -string NO; killall Dock
```

or

```
  defaults write com.apple.dock wm_ffm -bool false; killall Dock
```

or

```
  defaults write com.apple.mouse LSUIElement -string 1; sudo killall -HUP WindowServer  #warning, this killall cmd will quit all apps and log you out
```

note: anything changed with these commands can be removed by deleting the offending .plist file in ~/Library

---

#### Interesting

If any are wondering why [Focus Follows Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(computing)) is not (usually) the default behavior of the pointer in OS X:

> Focus-follows-mouse is not a particularly suitable input method for OS X because its menu bar was designed to be at the top of the screen. When you move the mouse out of your application window to get to the menus, if it crosses any other application's windows on the way, the menu changes.
> -scottishwildcat@stackoverflow

Comment: sorry... all done. Plz let us know if that works. TIA.

Comment: FocusFollowsMouse is for Terminal, not Dock? Either way, nothing happens :)

Comment: The latest version of VDP was published in 2005, how does this work together with Spaces etc on Mavericks?

Comment: This has nothing to do with focus stealing. This is about disabling a specific feature within Cmd-Tab.

Comment: @AlanShutko You are verifiably incorrect. As described, and what is happening, is the *pointer is stealing focus* from the user's intention of switching to another application. That's what focus stealing is, regardless if it is a feature within **Application Switcher** or not.

Comment: As grgarside explained, changing focus-follows-mouse doesn't affect this.

Comment: @AlanShutko that's not what he's saying. He is inquiring about the source of my inspiration, for the defaults command, which is from the terminal hook, it was worth a shot, and it failed. And I understand that the command doesn't work. But the command not working doesn't redefine the problem into something its not! Its still a *focus stealing* issue! omg ><

Comment: Well, this helped me. I guess learning to live with a problem is also a solution to the problem