# How can I force the application switcher to stop following the dock and instead show on my main display in Mavericks (OS X 10.9)?

Tags: macos, display, dock, application-switcher

I understand the App Switcher follows the Dock. Other [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107419/task-switcher-moves-to-non-primary-display-on-mavericks) [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/how-to-choose-on-which-display-application-switcher-shows) confirm as much.

However, is it possible via some hidden command-line preference to force the Application Switcher to display on the main display at all times? Whereas "main display" is the display in the *System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement* preference with the menu bar.

I personally have my dock hidden on my left-most display, but even switching the dock position to the bottom is a hassle since it requires first launching the dock from the desired display before switching the app switcher's location.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with losing the new features of Maverick's multiple displays, open System Preferences, click Mission Control, the uncheck the box that says, "Displays have separate spaces". Log out, then log back in, the problem should be resolved.

Comment: I tried his method, and it makes no difference. The app switcher still displays on the same screen as the dock, and does not on the same screen that is designated to show the menu (which was the behavior prior to Mavericks).

Comment: I, also, can confirm that this does NOT fix it under MacOS 11.1 (Big Sur).